# PHPExcel create pdf from a template

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, phpexcel, dompdf

I would like to generate a pdf file using php excel from a template using the  following code :

```
 //load our new PHPExcel library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        echo 'Library load succesfull';
//name the worksheet
        $objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/files/Timesheet_template.xlsx');
        echo 'Loading template successfull...';
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPexcel->getActiveSheet();
               $objWorksheet->getCell('C17')->setValue($td_3);
        $objWorksheet->getCell('D17')->setValue($td_4);
        $objWorksheet->getCell('E17')->setValue($td_5);
        $objWorksheet->getCell('F17')->setValue($td_6);

         $month = date('F');
        $year = date('Y');

        $data['user_data'] = $this->session->userdata('user');

        $user_id = $data['user_data']["employee_id"];
        $f_name = $data['user_data']["f_name"];
        $s_name = $data['user_data']["s_name"];
        $username = $data['user_data']["user_name"];
        $title = $data['user_data']["title"];
        $is_active = $data['user_data']["is_active"];
        $employee_type = $data['user_data']["employee_type"];
        // $filename = 'just_some_random_name.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name
//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
        echo 'ALMOST CREATING THE PDF FILE';
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
        $rendererLibrary = 'domPDF0.6.0beta3';
        $rendererLibraryPath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/system/helpers/dompdf';
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
        $rendererLibrary = 'domPDF0.6.0beta3';
        $rendererLibraryPath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/system/helpers/dompdf';
        if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
                        $objWriter, $rendererLibraryPath
                )) {
            die(
                    'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                    PHP_EOL .
                    ' as appropriate for your directory structure'
            );
        }

        echo 'pdf creation almost starting';
        // $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel,'pdf');
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($objPHPexcel);
        echo 'SUCCESS FULLY CREATED THE  PDF FILE...';
        $under_score = "_";
        $year = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $year);

        $inputFileType = $username . $under_score . $month . $under_score . $year . ".pdf";


        $objWriter->save("files/un_approved/" . $username . $under_score . $month . $under_score . $year . ".pdf");
```

I am using dompdf library to convert the  final template to pdf but the  file that's generated comes as corrupted and cannot be opened by Adobe Reder. Please advise what is the best way I should approach it?

Comment: Does a very simple example work to create a PDF file?

Comment: @ljacqu yes above is the  simplest example I have used, saving it as excel is successful but when I convert it to pdf it becomes corrupted.

Comment: Please try with the latest develop branch from github. There was an error in the HTML Writer (used by the PDF writer) that was fixed a couple of weeks ago